# User input assigned to variable in AppleScript then passed to "do shell script" command

Tags: applescript, xcode, bash, command-line

How do I grab input from the user in AppleScript and then pass the result of the variable to a `do shell script` command from within AppleScript itself?

For example, the user would type the answer `foo` to the following dialog box:

```
display dialog "Please enter your username" default answer ""
set the userID to the text returned of the result
do shell script "rm -rf /Users/$userID/.Trash/*" with administrator privileges
```

So in this instance, if I were to incorporate the answer of `foo` in lieu of `$userID`, it would read as the following when it executes the command:

```
display dialog "Please enter your username" default answer ""
set the userID to the text returned of the result
do shell script "rm -rf /Users/foo/.Trash/*" with administrator privileges
```

How do I pass that variable I grabbed earlier, in this case it would be $userID and incorporate it into the middle of the `shell script` call that I have made just above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This assigns the name entered to the variable `answer`.

```
display dialog "What's your name?" default answer ""
set answer to text returned of result
display dialog "Your name is " & answer
```

Comment: I know how to do that. I'll re-word my question to provide more clarity.

Comment: I don't want to add answer to a dialog as text, I want to pass, pipe, parse - whichever - it into the middle of a do shell script command

Comment: Instead of `display dialog` you put the command you need. The user input is stored in a variable. It seems you are actually asking how to concatenate strings. This is done with the `&` operator as shown in the last line of the example.

Comment: I used your script answer to answer my own question using it to do this. Thank you.

display dialog "Your name is " & answer & ", how are you?"

Answer (score 1):

You need string concatenation (the `&` operator) to combine the “fixed” parts of you string with the variable part. You also should use the `quoted form of` command to make sure that all user inputs are handled safely (i.e. spaces, wildcards, quote characters, and other characters that the shell treats specially—none of these are likely in a “short user name” but it always a good idea to handled things safely):

```
display dialog "Please enter your username" default answer ""
set the userID to the text returned of the result
do shell script "rm -rf /Users/"& quoted form of userID & "/.Trash/*" with administrator privileges
```

You can also pass the rest of the pathname through `quoted form of`, but you must not include the wildcard:

```
… "rm -rf " & quoted form of ("/Users/"& userID & "/.Trash/") & "*" …
```